# How to write the *args of function "avfilter_graph_send_command"(ffmpeg) when there has multiple drawtext targets?

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

I add 2 drawtext on ffmpeg drawtext filter, my filters descr is like this
"**drawtext=fontfile=simhei.ttf:fontcolor=#ff00ff@%1.0:fontsize=20:box=1.0:boxcolor=#00ff00@%1.0:x=0:y=0:text='123',drawtext=fontfile=simhei.ttf:fontcolor=#ff00ff@%1.0:fontsize=20:box=1.0:boxcolor=#00ff00@%1.0:x=0:y=200:text='456'**", so there have two characters watermark on video.
And this filter supports altering parameters via commands: reinit, so I use function: avfilter_graph_send_command(m_filter_graph, "drawtext", "reinit", m_filters_args, NULL, 0, 0) to modify the watermarks on realtime.(m_filters_args is my *arg variate)
I try snprintf the m_filters_args as
"**fontfile=simhei.ttf:fontcolor=#ff00ff@%1.0:fontsize=20:box=1.0:boxcolor=#00ff00@%1.0:x=0:y=10:text='112233',fontfile=simhei.ttf:fontcolor=#ff00ff@%1.0:fontsize=20:box=1.0:boxcolor=#00ff00@%1.0:x=0:y=200:text='445566'**", but it doesn't work as I wanted, it can only modify one drawtext, I want they can be both modified, I tried some other ways, but all failed.
can u tell me how to write the *arg or there has other ways to solve the problem.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an id to a filter e.g. `drawtext@abc=fontfile=...`. Then you would set command target as `drawtext@abc`.

Comment: hah, perfect!! buddy, thank U very very much!!!  So the next question is how to remove one drawtext or add one more drawtext correctly ? 